# Two network panel items rather than one

Tags: lubuntu

I installed ubuntu 16.04 and then ran `sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop` and `sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop` and `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop` to install other desktop environments. Then I removed xubuntu and kubuntu by `sudo apt remove xubuntu-desktop` and `sudo apt remove kubuntu-desktop`, and I kept `lubuntu` since I liked it.

Now I have two network panel items shown below:

[image]

I wonder what's the cause. Also there is two menu items for some apps on the lubuntu application menu.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Menu>Preferences->Desktop Session Settings, uncheck Network from the list, click OK, then reboot

For other double icons, they are due to package conflicts happened with multiple desktop environments

Comment: There is no `Desktop Session Settings`, there is only `Desktop Preferences`

Comment: Then try to find in startup applications. There must be two instances.